# Height change transition by content display

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I'm working in an Angular 9 app and I need to make an accordion menu. Everything works fine with my code except for the animation of the sub menus. I want to animate the content of a sub-menu item when display is change from'block' to 'none' and also animate it when is changing from 'block' to 'none'.

here is a couple of examples of what I need

https://codyhouse.co/demo/multi-level-accordion-menu/index.html

https://primer.fusepx.com/angular/

I also want to keep the code structure as much as possible. I just really need the content animation

Here is an stackblitz example with my code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t6rbdp

Comment: You cant animate display property in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.content {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 0 !important;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.content-open {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

As display which doest represent numeric values you cant do transition on that. So use properties like height.